# How to validate TextBox for website address input only in a Windows application

Tags: c#

I have a TextBox in a Windows application in C#.

I want to validate it so that the user can input only the website address in the proper format.

How can I do this?

Comment: I have also this question Thanks for asking..

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(userInput, System.UriKind.Absolute)
```

or use a regular expression:

[What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 0):

In web application, go to toolbox, then select validation tools. In validation, choose Regular Expression Validator-is a error messager. In the property of regular expression validator, choose ValidationExpression-then select Internet Url